# Scrapy - Do spider_idle is called when a DOWNLOAD_DELAY is specified?

Tags: scrapy

I'm writing a spider for scraping data about cars from a carsharing websites https://fr.be.getaround.com/. The objective is to divide my spider in two parts. First, it scrapes data for available cars and keeps unavailable cars aside. Second, once all information about available cars is scraped, thus at the end of the process, the spider scrapes additional information for unavailable cars. For this second part, I've added the `spider_idle` method in my spider. Doing so, it should be called once no available cars is remaining in the waiting list. However, I've added a `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` (5 seconds) and Autothrottle is enabled. I was wondering, do `spider_idle` will be called during the waiting time between each request (within the 5 seconds) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The `spider_idle` signal is only called when there are no further requests to process. It will not be called if no request happens to be in progress because the next request needs to wait for a given time to pass.